# Is it possible to utilize GPU for general purposes?

Tags: gpu, acceleration

In the PC is it possible to somehow utilize GPU from a dedicated grapihcs card for the purpose of increasing the total speed of the system (i.e. total computing power of CPU)? Or is that only possible for applications that can operate with GPU acceleration?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? There's an approach known as [`GPGPU`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General-purpose_computing_on_graphics_processing_units), for which several implementations exist, like [CUDA](http://www.nvidia.com/object/cuda_home_new.html) (for nVidia GPUs), or [OpenCL](https://www.khronos.org/opencl/).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why not using GPUs as a CPU?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11005746/why-not-using-gpus-as-a-cpu)

Comment: Thank you GPGPU was exactly what i was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

You can perfectly use GPU for other purposes than graphical topics. One famous usage was related to bitcoin mining (see https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Non-specialized_hardware_comparison).

More generally, you can get some benefit of computing with GPU when you have many elementary operation in parallel computing. A link would be: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General-purpose_computing_on_graphics_processing_units